# Silence 'Potential Fraud' and 'Potential Spam' phone calls without “Silence Unknown Callers”

Tags: iphone, ios

I get many calls where the caller will be listed as 'Potential Fraud' or 'Potential Spam'.  Is there a setting that I can use so that my phone won't ring when fraud or spam is listed on caller ID? This is very distracting for my work to get disrupted constantly throughout the day.

I don't want to enable “Silence Unknown Callers” because I still want to receive phone calls from people that are not in my contacts list (doctor's office, kid's school, etc.)

Comment: just curious - **where** listed?

Comment: It looks like this https://www.payetteforward.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/potential-spam-call-iphone-499x1080.jpg